# groovy error MissingPropertyException No such property: result for class: hudson.model.CauseAction

Tags: jenkins, groovy

we use using mail-ext and robot frame work to try to format all test suits detail in jenkins, and send out the report.

here is the groovy email-template we used now, its downloaded from github, https://github.com/JMcn/jenkins-email-ext-templates/blob/master/robot.groovy.

but this template reported following exception as below, i did not get similar error via googling, anything we missed for this template, thanks for any hint on this error.

```
<%
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
%>

........

<!-- System Test Result -->
<%
    def robotResults = false
    def actions = build.actions // List<hudson.model.Action>
    def robotTestResultAction = it.getAction("hudson.plugins.robot.RobotBuildAction")
    actions.each() { action ->
    if( robotTestResultAction != null ) {
    //if( action && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) ) {
        robotResults = true
%>
<TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="4"><B>test results</B></TD></TR>
    <TR style="border:1px solid #000;height:25px">
        <TD>total</TD>
        <TD>passed</TD>
        <TD>failure</TD>
        <TD>passrate</TD></TR>
    <TR style="border:1px solid #000;height:25px">
        <TD>${robotTestResultAction.getTotalCount()}</TD>
        <TD style="color:green"><%=robotTestResultAction.getTotalCount() - robotTestResultAction.getFailCount()%></TD>
        <TD style="color:red"><a style="color:red" href="${rooturl}${build.url}/${robotTestResultAction.urlName}">${robotTestResultAction.getFailCount()}</a></TD>
        <TD>${robotTestResultAction.overallPassPercentage}%</TD></TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" align="center">
<thead>
   <tr bgcolor="#F3F3F3">
      <td><b>test case name </b></td>
      <td><b>state</b></td>
      <td><b>execute duration</b></td>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%  def suites = action.result.allSuites
    suites.each() { suite ->
      def currSuite = suite
      def suiteName = currSuite.displayName
      // ignore top 2 elements in the structure as they are placeholders
      while (currSuite.parent != null && currSuite.parent.parent != null) {
        currSuite = currSuite.parent
        suiteName = currSuite.displayName + "." + suiteName
      } %>
<tr><td colspan="3"><b><%= suiteName %></b></td></tr>
<%    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SS")
      def execDateTcPairs = []
      suite.caseResults.each() { tc ->
        Date execDate = format.parse(tc.starttime)
        execDateTcPairs << [execDate, tc]


             }
      // primary sort execDate, secondary displayName
      execDateTcPairs = execDateTcPairs.sort{ a,b -> a[1].displayName <=> b[1].displayName }
      execDateTcPairs = execDateTcPairs.sort{ a,b -> a[0] <=> b[0] }
      execDateTcPairs.each() {
        def execDate = it[0]
        def tc = it[1]  %>
<tr>
  <td><%= tc.displayName %></td>
  <td style="color: <%= tc.isPassed() ? "#66CC00" : "#FF3333" %>"><%= tc.isPassed() ? "PASS" : "FAIL" %></td>
  <td><%= execDate %></td>
</tr>
<%    } // tests
    } // suites %>
</tbody>
</TABLE>
<%
  } // robot results
}
if (!robotResults) {
%>
<TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>接口测试结果</B></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD colspan="2">robotTestResultAction is null</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<%
    }
%>
<BR/>
```

Exception raised during template rendering: No such property: result for class: hudson.model.CauseAction groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: result for class: hudson.model.CauseAction     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:66) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296) at

after adjust script using Krzysztof Błażełek's suggestion, we got following error.

```
<!-- System Test Result -->
<%
    def robotResults = false
    def actions = build.actions // List<hudson.model.Action>
    //def robotTestResultAction = it.getAction("hudson.plugins.robot.RobotBuildAction")
    actions.each() { action ->
    //if( robotTestResultAction != null ) {
    if( action && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) ) {
        robotResults = true
```

Exception raised during template rendering: Cannot get property 'simpleName' on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'simpleName' on null object at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:47) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296) at SimpleTemplateScript211$_run_closure6.doCall(SimpleTemplateScript211.groovy:403) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ....

Comment: the error: `No such property: result for class: hudson.model.CauseAction`
the only line in your template that accesses `result` property:
`<%  def suites = action.result.allSuites`
and the error identifies the type of the `action` variable - [hudson.model.CauseAction](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/CauseAction.html)
 and it does not have `result` property.

Answer (score 1):

You have modified the template you have provided and that causes the problem. I believe you are iterating over all actions (not only `hudson.plugins.robot.RobotBuildAction`) and that is causing the exception. Try changing this part:

```
<!-- System Test Result -->
<%
    def robotResults = false
    def actions = build.actions // List<hudson.model.Action>
    def robotTestResultAction = it.getAction("hudson.plugins.robot.RobotBuildAction")
    actions.each() { action ->
    if( robotTestResultAction != null ) {
    //if( action && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) ) {
        robotResults = true
%>
```

into

```
<!-- System Test Result -->
<%
    def robotResults = false
    def actions = build.actions // List<hudson.model.Action>
    actions.each() { action ->
    if( action && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) ) {
        robotResults = true
        def robotTestResultAction = action
%>
```

Your code needs refactoring, but that's the quickest way to test if it works.

Comment: thanks for sharing your light. after refactoring script using if( action && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) ), i got Cannot get property 'simpleName' on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'simpleName'  error.

Comment: Krzysztof, any suggestion for the error? we have two jenkins server, the groovy script works well on other one, but does not work on this jenkins server. I also compare the plugin installation, both robot framework and email-ext plugin are there.

Comment: I feel like there is something wrong with this robot framework. Can you try reinstalling it on Jenkins? For some reason `action` is not null, but `action.class` returns null. It's this line that's failing right now: `if( action && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Revise as below,which solved my problem.

```
if( action.class && (action.class.simpleName.equals("RobotBuildAction") ) )
```